# DeprecationWarning attribute not found in Warnings.py

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, deprecation-warning

I'm trying to run the following cell in a Python Notebook .ipynb using Python 3.9.4:

```
import warnings
print(warnings.DeprecationWarning)
```

As a result, I get the following error:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) Cell In[1], line 2
> 1 import warnings
> ----> 2 print(warnings.DeprecationWarning)
>
> AttributeError: module 'warnings' has no attribute
> 'DeprecationWarning'

The reason why I want to check DeprecationWarning in warnings.py is because warnings.warn() takes as second parameter a warning which may be a DeprecationWarning:

```
warnings.warn("THIS IS A WARNING TEXT", warnings.DeprecationWarning)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DeprecationWarning` isn't a member of the `warnings` module; it's a built-in exception (see [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warning-categories)).

This means you can write:

```py
import warnings

def deprecated_function():
    warnings.warn("This is a deprecated function", DeprecationWarning)
```

Attempts to run `deprecated_function()` will result in:

```
.../warningtest.py:4: DeprecationWarning: This is a deprecated function
  warnings.warn("This is a deprecated function", DeprecationWarning)
```